# Can't access REST API URL from Linux to Windows in local network

Tags: rest

I am running REST API in Linux system. And I have Client App which is running in Windows in same intranet network. But I can't access REST API URL in my Windows browser.

Note:
Both REST API and Client app are in same local network.

Please help me.

Regards
Paul S

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Solved this issue with below commands

Actually it's silly thing. I have not enabled port in my Linux system firewall before.

1. Check Port Status

   ## netstat -na | grep 55555

   ## lsof -i -P |grep http

   httpd     5823   root    4u  IPv6  42212      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
2. Open firewall ports

   ## firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=55555/tcp --permanent

   success

   ## firewall-cmd --reload

   success
3. Check newly added port status

   ## lsof -i -P |grep http

   httpd     6595   root    4u  IPv6  43709      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
   httpd     6595   root    6u  IPv6  43713      0t0  TCP *:55555 (LISTEN)

   ## netstat -na |grep 55555

   tcp6       0      0 :::55555                :::*                    LISTEN